# How to print every element of an ARRAY in PL/SQL?

Tags: arrays, plsql

This is a pretty basic question, but here goes:

I have an array of VARCHAR2 strings in PL/SQL.

How can I print every element in that array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for i in my_array.first..my_array.last loop
  --print me
end loop;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in my_array.first..my_array.last loop

  dbms_output.put_line(my_array(i).col1Name||'  ' ||  my_array(i).col2Name|| '  '  ||my_array(i).col3Name);

end loop;
```